# serverless-offline custom plugin define env variables

Tags: serverless, serverless-offline

I want to boot a memory `mongodb` for my local development with `serverless`

This is the plugin I did

```
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server')

class MongoMemoryServerPlugin {

    constructor(){
        this.mongod

        this.hooks = {
            'before:offline:start:init': () => this.init(),
            'before:offline:start:end': () => this.end(),
        }

    }

    async init() {
        console.log('Starting Mongodb Memroy Server');
        this.mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
        process.env.MONGODB_URI = this.mongod.getUri();
    }

    async end() {
        console.log('Stopping Mongodb Memroy Server');
        if(this.mongod) this.mongod.stop()
    }
}

module.exports = MongoMemoryServerPlugin
```

And in my `serverless.yml` I have

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - ./plugin/mongodbMemoryServer.js
```

I have the log when starting and when ending but `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is not accessible from the serverless code

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

let cachedDb = null;

module.exports.connect = async function connect() {
    if (cachedDb) return cachedDb;

    if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) throw new Error('Environment variable MONGODB_URI not defined')

    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

    const db = client.db("db");

    cachedDb = db;
    return db;
}
```

when trying to connect, I have `Environment variable MONGODB_URI not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide that environment variable to the lambda you are deploying.

in serverless.yml, you can set it up in the following way in your lambda definition:

```
functions:
  my_function:
    handler: *****
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: *your_uri*
```